# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1,\ k\rm\ odd}\frac{1}{n^2}$ using fourier series.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f(x)=|x|$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$. A compute it's fourier coefficient, which are $c_n=\frac{-1+(-1)^n}{\pi n^2}$ if $n\neq 0$ and $c_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then, I could compute $\sum_{k\geq 1,k\rm\ odd}\frac{1}{n^2}$, but how can I deduce $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ ?

Comment: Note that we can always write $\sum_{n~\rm odd} f(n)+ \sum_{n~\rm even} f(n) = \sum_{n\geq 1} f(n)$ and we have $\sum_{n~\rm even} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{6^2} + \ldots = \frac{1}{4}\left[1 + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2}+\ldots\right]$

Comment: @Winther: You should put this as an answer :-)